# How does $S \otimes_R A$ become an $S$-algebra?

Tags: modules, tensor-products

Let $f : R \longrightarrow S$ is a ring homomorphism and $A$ is an $R$-algebra then in our lecture note  it has been stated that its scalar extension $S \otimes_R A$ is an $S$-algebra.
How is that possible? I know that the scalar extension is a $S$-module given by the well defined operation $s(s_1 \otimes x):=ss_1 \otimes x$. Also I know that if $A$ and $B$ are two $R$-algebra then their tensor product $A \otimes B$ is again an $R$-algebra with the well-defined operation given by $(a \otimes b)(a' \otimes b'):=aa' \otimes bb'$.

Now from these two facts how can I reach at the desired conclusion? Please help me in this regard.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are the rings commutative?

Comment: That should be! But it is not mentioned in my lecture note.

Comment: This is the main cause of my confusion.

Comment: My answer doesn't assume commutativity but it seems that you lecture notes do. In any case, commutativity makes sure that it doesn't matter whether the action is left or right, any action of commutative ring is automatically both but in general you must distinguish between them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to be careful about actions being left or right if the rings are not commutative. In general, if you have $AB$-bimodule $M$ (i.e. left $A$-action and right $B$-action) and $BC$-bimodule $N$ (left $B$-action and right $C$-action), then the tensor product $M\otimes_B N$ is $AC$-module:

$$a(m\otimes n) = (am)\otimes n,\ (m\otimes n)c = m\otimes(nc)$$ and if $M$ and $N$ are moreover algebras, then the tensor product will again be algebra.

In your case you have $S\otimes_R A$. To make it into $S$ module, you need to have

- left $S$-action on $S$ - this is just multiplication in $S$,
- right $R$-action on $S$ - this is given by $f$, $s.r := sf(r)$,
- left $R$-action on $A$ that you have since $A$ is an algebra.

Algebra multiplication is defined as you wrote it. The left $S$-action is defined as $$s'(s\otimes a) = (s's)\otimes a.$$

Comment: I have just proved it myself. First I thought that if $f(R) \subset Z(S)$ then we are through. Because it is needed to prove that $S \otimes A$ is a $R$-algebra which leads to our desired conclusion but I saw at last the ring $S$ should also be commutative otherwise the multiplication in the algebra $A$ as a ring is not bilinear then.